# Using MKL-optimized numpy.dot() with 3d arrays

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading, numpy, intel-mkl

I've been trying to optimize my code for some time now, and just realized that there is a huge performance penalty whenever I try to use `numpy.dot` with an array of 3 or more dimensions.

As an example, this code:

```
def ti():
  r = random.rand(8,256,32**2)
  p = random.rand(32**2,256)
  o = empty((8,256,256))
  for k in xrange(100):
    dot(r,p,o)
```

runs 50x slower than the following conversion (on an 8-core macbook pro):

```
def ti2():
  r = random.rand(8*256,32**2)
  p = random.rand(32**2,256)
  o = empty((8*256,256))
  for k in xrange(100):
    dot(r,p,o)
```

It turns out the first block of code doesn't use multiple cores, which makes me wonder if it is using MKL at all.

Is there a way to force the first block of code to be multithreaded and use MKL without explicitly translating it into the second block of code? In reality the arrays I'm working with are 4d and 5d, and I'd like to avoid collapsing all of the beginning dimensions (I also perform other operations on the array, like taking the sum over the 2nd dimension of the original 4d array which would become much more complicated if I stacked the entire array into only 2 dimensions). Alternatively, to make the rest of the code readable, how much of a performance hit would I suffer by reshaping the array from 4d down to 2d for the dot product, then back to 4d after that step? Or is there a more efficient way to convert the data between two shapes?

Update:
I've also experimented with simple nested for loops to iterate through the first dimensions and it seems to work relatively well, but im new to cython and haven't been able to convert it to cython yet. Would a specialized cython functions add much of a performance gain?

Answer (score 1):

There is no builtin way.  There is an [open issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/619) about this on the numpy bug tracker, and a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-dev/hSKQaZZOutw) on the mailing list.  Both of these are fairly old, so it doesn't look like there's been progress on this for a couple years.

I did find [this blog post](http://www.huyng.com/posts/faster-numpy-dot-product/) that links to a small library called `fastdot` that claims to do high-dimensional dot products more quickly, but I haven't used it personally so I can't say for sure how well (or if) it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `np.tensordot`, as it does the reshaping and 2D dot under the hood.

```
o = np.tensordot(r, p, [[-1], [-2]])
```

As for performance hit, it seems the reshapes can be done without making copies in this particular case (both `r` and `p` are C-contiguous) and in that case there should be practically no effect on performance. Sadly it does not support an output argument, but you could modify the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.9.x/numpy/core/numeric.py#L1106) if you really need this.